# Magento Custom Module named Bms_Scan not getting Displayed in Advanced Page of Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, configuration, third-party-module

```
Config.xml file

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   Bms
 * @package    Bms_Scan
 * @author     ModuleCreator
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bms_Scan>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bms_Scan>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <scan>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bms_Scan</module>
                    <frontName>scan</frontName>
                </args>
            </scan>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <scan>
                    <file>scan.xml</file>
                </scan>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <scan>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bms_Scan</module>
                    <frontName>scan</frontName>
                </args>
            </scan>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <scan module="scan">
                <title>Scan</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="scan">
                                <title>Scan List</title>
                                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scan</action>
                            </items>
                            <items1 module="scan">
                                <title>New Scan</title>
                                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scancrm</action>
                            </items1>
                            <items2 module="scan">
                                <title>Hospitals</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scanhospital</action>
                            </items2>
                            <items3 module="scan">
                                <title>Doctors</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scandoctors</action>
                            </items3>
                            <items4 module="scan">
                                <title>Confirmed scan</title>
                                <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scanconfirmed</action>
                            </items4>
                            <items5 module="scan">
                                <title>Completed scans</title>
                                <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scancompleted</action>
                            </items5>
                            <items6 module="scan">
                                <title>Price List</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scanprices</action>
                            </items6>
                            <items7 module="scan">
                                <title>Postponed scans</title>
                                <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scanpostponed</action>
                            </items7>
                </children>
            </scan>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Bms_Scan>
                            <title>Scan Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Bms_Scan>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <scan>
                    <file>scan.xml</file>
                </scan>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <scan>
                <class>Bms_Scan_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>scan_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </scan>
            <scan_mysql4>
                <class>Bms_Scan_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <scan>
                        <table>scan</table>
                    </scan>
                    <scancrm>
                        <table>scancrm</table>
                    </scancrm>
                    <scanhospital>
                        <table>scanhospital</table>
                    </scanhospital>
                    <scandoctors>
                        <table>scandoctors</table>
                    </scandoctors>
                    <scanprices>
                        <table>scans_pricelist</table>
                    </scanprices>
                </entities>
            </scan_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <scan_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Bms_Scan</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </scan_setup>
            <scan_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </scan_write>
            <scan_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </scan_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <scan>
                <class>Bms_Scan_Block</class>
            </scan>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <scan>
                <class>Bms_Scan_Helper</class>
            </scan>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>

adminhtml.xml File

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <scan module="scan">
                        <title>Scan</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>               
                        <children>
                            <items module="scan">
                                <title>Scan List</title>
                                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scan</action>
                            </items>
                            <items1 module="scan">
                                <title>New Scan</title>
                                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scancrm</action>
                            </items1>
                            <items2 module="scan">
                                <title>Hospitals</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scanhospital</action>
                            </items2>
                            <items3 module="scan">
                                <title>Doctors</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scandoctors</action>
                            </items3>
                            <items4 module="scan">
                                <title>Confirmed scans</title>
                                <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scanconfirmed</action>
                            </items4>
                            <items5 module="scan">
                                <title>Completed scans</title>
                                <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scancompleted</action>
                            </items5>
                            <items6 module="scan">
                                <title>Price List</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scanprices</action>
                            </items6>
                            <items7 module="scan">
                                <title>Postponed scans</title>
                                <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                                <action>scan/adminhtml_scanpostponed</action>
                            </items7>
                        </children>
                    </scan>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```